# Unable to import Biopython in Wing IDE

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew, biopython, wing-ide

I installed Python3 with Homebrew, and then I installed Biopython using pip.

The path to Python3 is :
`/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`

The path to biopython is: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.83)`

However, when I use Wing IDE to try to use `import Bio` import the biopython package, I get the following error message:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsjYV.png)

I've also tried `import biopython` and `import bio` to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Wing needs to pointed to the python environment that you want to use by using the Project > Project Properties dialog to set the Python Executable setting to /opt/homebrew/bin/python3